# es6 export/import multiple classes - instanceof returns false

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

test1.js

```
export class ValidationError extends Error {
  constructor (msg) {
    super(msg)
  }
}

export class ServerError extends Error {
  constructor (msg) {
    super(msg)
  }
}
```

test2.js

```
import * as errors from './test1'

const inst = new errors.ValidationError('msg')

console.log(inst instanceof errors.ValidationError)
```

When I run test2 the output is `false` (`true` expected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't `import`. It is Babel. The inheritance of built-in classes is [ES6 feature](http://www.2ality.com/2013/03/subclassing-builtins-es6.html). It won't work well in transpiled ES5 code.

The code above will likely result in `inst` as a mix-in of `ValidationError` and an instance of `Error`.

The solution is to not transpile the features that are already supported by Node. A custom preset should be used, e.g. [`babel-preset-es2015-node6`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015-node6)  or [`babel-preset-eslatest-node6`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-eslatest-node6).

Comment: Perfect - it works! Meantime I found other solution - instead of extending native Error class it's possible to extend https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-error. But your solution is obviously better because it does not require additional dependencies.

Comment: Did `es6-error` work for you in this case? It could hit the same problem with `instanceof`.

Comment: Yes, when extending "es6-error" instead of "Error" it works.